# Squatting with bruised knee

Tags: weightlifting

So these past couple weekends, a couple and friends and I have gotten together and played soccer. Somehow, I always manage to run into someone, and injuring (bruising?) my knee. The inside of my knee is tender, and I feel it when at the bottom of bodyweight squats. Last time this happened, I just skipped squats completely for the next workout or two, then it seemed to be fine. However, I don't really want to hinder my squat progress too much, so I was wondering if it is still okay to squat with a bruised knee (at a lighter weight). I am deloading from 140 to around 95, as per suggestion of a form check I posted, to make sure I fix my major buttwink.

So real question, skip squats due to minor knee bruising? Or will I be fine, especially since I am deloading 30% to work on form?

(the program I am following is Ice Cream Fitness at the moment, in case it may be of use)

Comment: Since you are working on form, if the knee allows you to complete the motion with good alignment and without deviating or working around it,  you should be ok.  However if this is a recurrent problem you may want to have your knee checked out professionally.  Pain can cause [muscle inhibition](http://www.muscleactivationtechnician.com/pages/faq) which can work against what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's just bruising, and you have full range of motion you should be OK.  Just don't get in too big a hurry with progressing your lifts to the point where you lift in a very injured state.

Working around an injured body part for a day or two really isn't that big a deal in the grand scheme of things.